# add span in paragraph on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like it should be super simple, but can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Basically what I am trying to do is add a span as the first character of every `<p>` on hover. Currently using JQuery as my DOM manipulation library, so JQuery solutions welcomed.

So:

```
<p>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</p>
```

would become

```
<p><span class="comment">comment</span>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.</p>
```

Note that I can not add the span prior, since i don't have access to the text till it is in the DOM.

Comment: _“Currently using JQuery”_ – currently not seeing any of that. And a character is something different than a _word_, btw.

Comment: I meant I was using JQuery as my DOM manipulation library. Sorry I was't clear on that. Added clarification to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this on your script tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("p").hover(function () {
        $(this).prepend('<span class="comment">comment</span>');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children(".comment").remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is JavaScript, but I'm sure you can find a doc that says how to do it with jQuery. Just use the insertAdjacentHTML function. You can read how it works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: Thanks, this is much nicer then my solution. As long as there are no browser compatibly issues I will go this.

Comment: @abritez if you scroll a bit further on that page, you'll see a browser compatibility section.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handled it

```
var position = 0;
var ele = "<span>comment</span>"
$('p').html($('p').html().substring(0,position) +  ele  + $('p').html().substring (position));
```

Edit:

Thank to A. Wolff this works

$( "comment" ).prependTo( "p" );

Comment: you should use `.prepend()` instead: `$('p').prepend(ele);`